# Props not being passed to relative url in ReactJS/react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code, where in `{...props}` a function is being passed down from a parent component. In all the routes, this function is available in props apart from those routes that have a `/:id`.

Any ideas why?

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/" render={() => (<ManageClients {...props}/>)}/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/new-client" render={() => (<AddClient {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/admins" render={() => (<ManageAdmins {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/files" render={() => (<ManageFiles {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/new-file" render={() => (<AddFile {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/update-client/:id" render={(props) => (<EditClient {...props} />) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/update-file/:id" render={(props) => (<EditFile {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/clone/:id" render={(props) => (<CloneClient {...props}/>) }/>
  <Route exact="exact" path="/new-admin"render={() => (<NewAdmin {...props}/>) }/> </Switch>
```

Comment: When you have an :id, you're doing `(props) => (<CloneClient {...props}/>)` while when you don't have it, you're doing `() => (<ManageClients {...props}/>)`. Remove props as an input param it the first case and it should work the same way?

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that. The problem is, I have to pass in the props in the first param to be able to access `this.props.match.params` in those particular components. Without it, those components don't work because my functions can't access the params.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This still returns `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` when the route loads :(

Comment: Which one did you use?, if you used `otherProps={otherProps}` you should use `this.props.otherProps.match.params`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to pass the parent props and the routes props separately

`<Route exact="exact" path="/clone/:id" render={(otherProps) => <CloneClient {...props} otherProps={otherProps} /> }/>`

or this if you want to merge them:

`<Route exact="exact" path="/clone/:id" render={(otherProps) => <CloneClient {...props, ...otherProps} /> }/>`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was almost there. I had to remove the `<Switch>` around my routes, and then write the route as:

```
<Route
    exact="exact"
    path="/update-client/:id"
    render={otherProps => (
    <EditClient {...props} {...otherProps} />
    )}
/>
```